# why table cell is not reading the table row in parent component?

Tags: html, angular

I have 2 components here: app.component.html and app-server.component.html

app.component.html

```
  <table class="table" style="width:200px;">
        <tr>
            <td>Names</td>
            <td>Age</td>

        </tr>


     <tr><app-server-element *ngFor="let student of students" [student]='student'></app-server-element></tr>

</table>
```

server-element.component.html:

```
 <td class="column">{{student.name}}</td>
 <td class="column">{{student.age}}</td>
```

but the result is like this why?:

[image]

Comment: You need to iterate over `tr` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the problem others have suggesting - there seems to be another problem. Your `<app-server-element *ngFor="let student of students" [student]='student'></app-server-element>` acts as a cell because it is a direct child of your `tr`. The `td` elements inside `app-server-element` have no effect. You could use replace in your directive to get rid of the wrapper - that way the `td` element would be a direct child of the `tr` element and it would work as expected.

**Edit**

After gathering more information regarding your problem, please make the following changes to your code:

Change the `server-element.component.ts` to:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: '[appServerElement]',
    templateUrl: './server-element.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./server-element.component.css']
})
export class ServerElementComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    appServerElement: { name: string, age: string };

    constructor() {
        //
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //
    }

}
```

and change `selector: 'app-server-element'` to `selector: '[appServerElement]'`.

Change the `app.component.html` to the following:

```
<table class="table" style="width:200px;">
    <tr>
        <td>Names</td>
        <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr [appServerElement]="student" *ngFor="let student of students"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thx for your reply @Vladimir Zdenek . what are you suggesting me to change ? <td> in the <app-server-component> to <tr>?

Comment: Post the code of your `app-server-element` so I can help you.

Comment: that is all the code in <app-server-element> only those 2 <td>:  <td class="column">{{student.name}}</td>
 <td class="column">{{student.age}}</td>

Comment: It must have a JS part to it as well. That is what I am interested in.

Comment: there is no any js part

Comment: I highly doubt that. There should be a file called server-element.component.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145097/discussion-between-vladimir-zdenek-and-mikethetechy).

Answer (score 0):

As ankit suggested you need to iterate of `<tr>`:

```
 <table class="table" style="width:200px;">
    <tr>
        <td>Names</td>
        <td>Age</td>

    </tr>


 <tr *ngFor="let student of students"><app-server-element *ngFor="let student of students" [student]='student'></app-server-element></tr>
```

your code iterate over `app-server-element` which results:

```
<tr>
<app-server-element></app-server-element>
<app-server-element></app-server-element>
<app-server-element></app-server-element>
<app-server-element></app-server-element>
</tr>
```

while you want: `<tr><app-server-element></app-server-element></tr>
              <tr><app-server-element></app-server-element></tr>
              <tr><app-server-element></app-server-element></tr>`

Comment: thx for your reply @Ori Price. ... i do not have problem iterating my data here... the problem is the age is not show in a <td> cell..instead it is sticking with the name<td> cell